# How to Display Custom Taxonomies in an Un-ordered HTML List

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Having a Custom Taxonomy function like below, can you please let me know how I can list all of my Taxonomies in an unordered html list

```
enter code here
function create_conference_taxonomy() {
 $topiclabels = array(
 'name' => 'Topic',
 'singular_name' => 'topic',
 'search_items' => 'Search topics',
 'popular_items' => 'Popular topics',
 'all_items' => 'All topics',
 'parent_item' => null,
 'parent_item_colon' => null,
 'edit_item' => 'Edit topic',
 'update_item' => 'Update topic',
 'add_new_item' => 'Add new topic',
 'new_item_name' => 'New topic name',
 'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate topics with commas',
 'add_or_remove_items' => 'Add or remove topics',
 'choose_from_most_used' => 'Choose from common topics',
 'menu_name' => 'Conference topics',
  );
  register_taxonomy( 'conference_topics', 'conference_session',
    array(
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'labels' => $topiclabels,
  'query_var' => true,
  'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
  'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'topics' )
   )
  );
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies)?

Comment: Hi Vancoder, Actually I did but they seem too confusing for me.I am guessing to use following code `<?php 
$args=array(
  'name' => 'genre'
);
$output = 'objects'; // or objects
$taxonomies=get_taxonomies($args,$output); 
if  ($taxonomies) {
  foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
    echo '<p>' . $taxonomy->name . '</p>';
  }
}  
?>` but I cant figure out how to use it!

Comment: Your code specifies only to list taxonomies called 'genre' - which rather defeats the purpose of 'list all of my Taxonomies'. Are you sure you mean taxonomies, and not terms?

Comment: Sorry Vancoder, I think you get the point I am actually looking to find a way to display terms? I mean all topics like romance, Commedy ,.. which user can create true above code